# What is the Ruby equivalent of Node.js' socket.io?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, rubygems, websocket, socket.io

If I wanted to translate my node application that uses socket.io into a Ruby on Rails application what are the options for replacing socket.io? (Essentially looking for a socket server for Ruby)

http://socket.io/

Plan to translate the application below:
http://www.tokbox.com/blog/creating-chat-roulette-with-node-js-socket-io-and-opentok/

Comment: You can actually have Node.JS on your Rails server, and use Socket.io (Node.JS is great at dealing with websockets)

Comment: @MrYoshiji I suspected that there was a way to do this, do you mind elaborating?  

I assummed one could pass data between servers somehow...XML?JSON? but Im not certain how

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend the [Faye Ruby implementation](http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby.html) as a solid server-side realtime component. It's not a direct port of socket.io but provides you with the realtime infrastructure and some well define messaging concepts that will help you port most realtime applications.

You can find more options via the [realtime web tech guide](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Cramp.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the [Plezi framework](http://www.plezi.io)?

You can use it either as a separate framework or to [augment Rails/Sinatra by adding websocket functionality](http://www.plezi.io/docs/with_rack_app).

It runs using the [Iodine](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) server and supports native websockets, RESTful routes and HTTP streaming, so it's easy to have a fallback position such as long-pulling, much like socket.io does when web sockets don't work.

It's interesting and easy to develop with and has native support for Redis, so it allows websocket broadcasts between processes and machines... although it's still under development, it's full of potential.

A broadcast/echo WebSocket app can look like this:

```
require 'plezi'

class Echo

  def index
    "this is an echo server - use websockets to connect. test with: https://www.websocket.org/echo.html"
  end

  def on_message data
    _echo data
    broadcast :_echo, data
  end

  def _echo data
    response << data
  end
end

Plezi.route '/', Echo
```

You can actually put the code in the irb console and the server will start the moment you exit irb using the `exit` command.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Pubnub](http://www.pubnub.com/), it has many wrappers including ruby.

Documentation is really easy to follow and they have many tutorials.

I have used Pubnub on many rails projects, including raspberry pie projects.

Rails 5 now has ActionCable built in, which means websockets are now standard with Rails!

Comment: PubNub is now *very* expensive for web work. If you get under 100 uniques a day you're fine on the free plan, but go over that and you bump up to their lowest plan at **$149/mo**. Exceed that plan and you go up to **$399/mo**. This is different from a year ago when they had plans for as little as $15/mo.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP is looking to build a socket.io server in ruby not outsource the chat to a PaaS.